# Error en el ngModule al heredar Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

Buen día,

Estoy tratando de heredar desde un componente a otro, pero cuando cargo el componente que esta heredando, el angular me bota como error todos los lugares donde he utilizado el ngModule

Nota: Estoy usando Angular 9

Este es el componente del que quiero heredar

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reportes-catalogacion',
  templateUrl: './reportes-catalogacion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reportes-catalogacion.component.scss']
})
export class ReportesCatalogacionComponent implements OnInit {
prueba:string = 'sadad';
constructor(public serviceFactoryGraphicService: ServiceFactoryGraphicService, public text: textoModuloAdm, public spinner: NgxSpinnerService, public ajax: AjaxService, public encript: DycpService) {}
```

Modulo

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(router),
    LayoutModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
    , FormsModule
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
],
declarations: [
    ReportesCatalogacionComponent
],
providers: [
    AjaxService
    , CreateHighChartService
    , ServiceFactoryGraphicService
    , AjaxService
], 
entryComponents: [
    GraphicalAmChardComponent
  ]
})
```

Componente al que voy a heredar
Trate de inicializar la variable para ver si funcionaba y aun así seguía generando el mismo error
agregue el CommonModule y FormsModule al modulo de cada componente y aun así se seguía generando el error, también añadí el BrowserModule al modulo raíz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-indicators-default',
  templateUrl: './indicators-default.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./indicators-default.component.scss']
})

export class IndicatorsDefaultComponent extends ReportesCatalogacionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(public serviceFactoryGraphicService: ServiceFactoryGraphicService, public text: textoModuloAdm, public spinner: NgxSpinnerService, public ajax: AjaxService, public encript: DycpService) {
super(serviceFactoryGraphicService, text, spinner, ajax, encript);
this.prueba = 'asdasd';
  }
}
```

Modulo

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(router),
    LayoutModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
],
declarations: [
    IndicatorsDefaultComponent
],
providers: [
    AjaxService,
    CreateHighChartService,
    ServiceFactoryGraphicService,
    AjaxService
],
entryComponents: [
    GraphicalAmChardComponent
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

El error hace referencia a FormsModule, pero vi que lo agregaste. Podrías cambiar el orden

imports: [
...
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
],